# Is there a discontinuous closed injection of the first Baire class?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, polish-spaces

Is it possible to find a **discontinuous** function $f\colon X\to X$ on a Polish space $X$ such that

- $f$ is injective,
- $f$ is closed (maps closed sets to closed sets), and
- $f$ is of [Baire first class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function)?

This is a rather goofy question with a probably easy solution...